# What are some best object-oriented design practices?

Tags: oop, modeling

I didn't find any question that would be this general.

Please post whatever you find to be a useful rule for oject-oriented design.

Answer (score 46):

There are many, many OOD practices (Google it!) if you had to pick over others I would go with [SOLID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID) an acronym for;

1. [Single Responsibility Principal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)
2. [Open/closed principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle)
3. [Liskov substitution principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle)
4. [Interface segregation principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle)
5. [Dependency inversion principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle)

Comment: Interesting that googling it brought me here at the top of the list.

Answer (score 19):

I have recommended the [Head First Design Patterns](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596007124) book many times.

It gives you a good intro to the [GoF Design Patterns](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201633612) (a more advanced book that you also should read), but also a good intro to sound OOP design principles.

[image]

Comment: +1 for head first DP , I too recommend it .

Comment: @JørnE.Angeltveit literally just purchased the headfirst book on your recommendation - i saw some pdfs online and it's definitely looking good. thx

Answer (score 12):

Few other principles are

1. **"Hollywood principle"** which means
   lower layers should not depend on
   higher layers.
2. **"Favor composition
   over inheritance"** - composition
   allows changing/adding behavior at
   runtime and is more maintainable
3. **"Program to an interface, not to the
   implementation"** - always use
   abstraction as a way of referencing
   instead of direct coupling to the
   concrete class

I suggest you to look into "Head first - OOAD" as well..

Comment: Isn't "Hollywood principle" which sounds like "Don't call us, we'll call you" more about the inversion of control (e.g. Reactor pattern, Observer pattern and alike)? What you are talking about is useful nevertheless but it's part of what is called Dependency Inversion Principle AFAIK.

Answer (score 4):

Good summary of OOD principles can be found here:
https://web.archive.org/web/20190714115656/http://butunclebob.com/ArticleS.UncleBob.PrinciplesOfOod

The author is Robert C. Martin (also known as Uncle Bob), programming specialist with more than 40 years of experience in programming.

Articles are taken from his book "Clean Code" which IMHO is a really good material for OOP design principles.

Comment: Just a suggestion that in addition to sharing a helpful supplemental link, it's useful for SO readers to take the time to summarize some of the cogent points from the material you're referencing.

Comment: Thanks for advice. Will keep it in mind.

Comment: Dead link! The referred page is blank.

Comment: Your link is dead.You should update your answer or delete it.

Comment: I've updated the post.
Now it's referring to Uncle's Bob web site.

Answer (score 2):

Read other people's code and try to design class diagrams.
It will give you an idea of how other people think through problem solving.
That helps me a lot. Especially frameworks.

Answer (score 2):

The best of OOP nothing, any approach that's fit for your project is best. But it is important what are OOP practices before choosing any/many from them for your project.

1: APIE: Abstraction, Polymorphism, Inheritance, Encapsulation.

2: [SOLID Principle.](http://code.tutsplus.com/series/the-solid-principles--cms-634)

3: [OO analysis and design.](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596008678)

4: [Design patterns.](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596007124)

5: [Code refactoring.](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201485672)

6: [Effective Java.](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321356683)

Answer (score -1):

In my view,I think if you want to learn about Object Oriented design you should try to play with Smalltalk language since it is the language which started Object Oriented programming.

We have an alternative now called Squeak which is open source.SOLID as out fellow mate mentioned also gives you a great idea about OOPS.

All the best on your OOPS journey.

You can check out Squeak on [Squeak on Web.](http://squeak.org/)